# how to zoom dual x axis at same time in highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

need to zoom dual x axis at same point of time and also i need to show the x and y axis values on tool tip. how to do that. Please find my code in js fiddle in the link

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            marginRight: 80, // like left
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        navigator: {
                enabled:true,
                    xAxis: {
                        labels: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                },
        scrollbar: {
                    enabled: true
                },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        }, {
            opposite: true,
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        }],
        yAxis: [{
            lineWidth: 1,
            title: {
                text: 'Primary Axis'
            }
        }, {
            lineWidth: 1,
            opposite: true,
            title: {
                text: 'Secondary Axis'
            }
        }],

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            xAxis: 1
        }, {
            data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
            yAxis: 1
        }]
    });
});
```

in this chart how can i zoom top and bottom x axis and on tool tip how to show the both x axis values

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/S2srp/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can set `linkedTo` for second yAxis, see: http://jsfiddle.net/S2srp/2/

Comment: thanks a lot its working fine. how to show both x axis values on tooltip, and i am getting trouble to show hide the top x axis

Comment: You need to create your own formatter, and set shared tooltip. Read [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip).

Comment: @PawelFus Thanks for this answer, it works as expected. However, this comes with a side-effect where hiding `Series 2` from legend hides all the data on the graph. 
Any inputs on how this can be avoided? Ex. Hiding a legend should hide respective line chart only.

Comment: Did you try removing `xAxis: 1`? That was in OP's config, perhaps expected behaviour.